# JQuery tablesorter: Modify how it sorts empty cells

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a big table and want to sort using tablesorter. The problem I'm dealing with is that tablesorter act as 0 for empty cells when sorting with numbers. How can I push the empty cells to bottom?

As an example, tablesorter sorts like that

```
-5
-4
-1
<empty cell>
<empty cell>
6
7
15
23
```

I want to sort as

```
-5
-4
-1
6
7
15
23
<empty cell>
<empty cell>
```

Comment: A dirty workaround would be to insert <span style="display:non;">zzzz</span> into the empty cells :p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify your own text extraction function:

```
 $(table).tablesorter({          
    textExtraction: function (node)              
        { 
            if (node.innerHTML.length == 0)
            {
                return "999999999";  // or some suitably large number!
            }
            else
            {
                return node.innerHTML;
            }           
        }       
} );
```